# use OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I want to understand the concept of the TSource, Tkey by the example.

We have the code

```
        class Pet
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        public static void OrderByEx1()
        {
            Pet[] pets = { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
                           new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
                           new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } };

            IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);

            foreach (Pet pet in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pet.Name, pet.Age);
            }
        }

        /*
         This code produces the following output:

         Whiskers - 1
         Boots - 4
         Barley - 8
        */
```

Can we say TSource is "pet", key is "Age" and pet => pet.Age is

```
 Func<TSource, TKey>?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `TSource` is the type `Pet`, and `TKey` is the type `int`. So not using type inference, you'd have:

```
IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy<Pet, int>(pet => pet.Age);
```

`TSource` and `TKey` are the [*generic type parameters*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) of the method. You can think of them as being like generic type parameters for classes... so in `List<T>`, `T` is the type parameter, and if you write:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
```

then the *type argument* here is `string` (so you can say that `T=string` in this case, in a hand-wavy way).

The difference in your case is that the compiler is *inferring* the type arguments for you, based on the method call arguments.

Comment: Do you mean <Pet, int> is omitted in the code? And what is Func here?

Comment: @Love: It's inferred by the compiler. See MSDN on generic methods for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) for `Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>`

- TSource

  The type of the elements of source.
- TKey

  The type of the key returned by keySelector. Parameters source Type:  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

  A sequence of values to order. keySelector Type: System.Func

  A function to extract a key from an element.

So `TSource` = `Pet`; `TKey` = `int`

Comment: Then what is Func<TSource, TKey> here?

Comment: Func<TSource, TKey> is  keySelector a function to extract a key from an element. here is you can find full function description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet's [book](http://manning.com/skeet2/) covers these details quite thoroughly.  That being said, in this case it's useful to see how the Generic's playout by using the mouse float tool in visual studio.

[image]